# C++ std::set index of insert

Tags: c++

I've faced a following issue:

Suppose I've got a std::set named Numbers, containing n values. I want to insert (n+1)th value (equal to x), which I in advance know not to be in the set yet. What I need is some way to check, in which position will it be inserted, or, equivalently, how many of elements less than x are already contained in Numbers.

I definitely know some ways of doing it at O(n), but what I need is O(log(n)). Theoretically it might be possible as std::set is usually implemented as Binary Search Tree (presumably O(log(n)) is possible only if it stores information about sizes of each subtree in each vertex). The question is whether it's technically possible, and if it is, how to do it.

Comment: Counting elements before the inserted leaf in a BST is not an O(log N) operation on a regular BST, std::set or other. Are you thinking of some kind of heap structure?

Comment: It's more like modified BST, which has additional data (left_subtree_size, right_subtree_size) appended to each vertex. AFAIU, keeping this structure consistent will cost something like doubling time for most algorithms and adding O(n) to the BST size itself, which is an overhead, but for my task it's an acceptible one.

Comment: A homegrown BST should be able to deal with this. Might I suggest a single tree-size value per vertex.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Actually, for both of them :)

Answer (score 1):

There's no "position" in set, there's iterator and set gives you no promises regarding implementation. You can, probably use lower/upper_bound and count elements, but I don't think it's going to take internals into account.

Answer (score 1):

All of the `set` functions are going to work with iterators; the iterator of a `set` is bidirectional, not random-access, so determining the position will be an O(n) operation.

You don't need to know the position to insert a new element in the set, and insertions are O(log n).

Comment: I'm aware of the fact that iterator of 'set' is bidirectional, I only hoped that solely for 'index_of' issues 'set' might have some specific mechanisms that make use of its "ordered"-ness.

Comment: As for "don't-need-to-know-position": unfortunately, the very "index_of" is what I need for my algorithm

Comment: @DmitriyKorolevich, `set` is generally implemented as a tree, and the only way to get the relative position in a tree is to walk it which is exactly what the iterator does.

Comment: I slightly disagree on the "the only way to get the relative position in a tree"-point. Assuming each vertex stores its left and right subtree sizes, you could calculate index with O(log(n)) whithout actually traversing all of elements that are less then x. This implementation even wouldn't spoil asymptotic complexity of set, although would definitely increase constants, both for memory and for speed.  As `set` is designed for general productivity, though, I'm afraid it's not the point here, and, therefore, for this thing I'll probably have to write my own tree, I assume :(

Comment: nodes in the std::set are not required to store their subtree sizes that I know of. There is no standard way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can find "position" where this new element would be inserted in O(lon(n)) using `set::lower_bound`, but it's just an iterator. std::set::iterator is bidirectional, not random access, so you cannot count how many elements are smaller than that new one in O(lon(n))

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use set::lower_bound(), which time, according to this (http://lafstern.org/matt/col1.pdf) document, should be proportional to log N

Comment: The problem is that, although `set::lower_bound()` is by itself O(log(n)), the only way I see for checking number of elements less than x is performing    `(std::set(Numbers.begin(), std::lower_bound(Numbers.begin(), Numbers.end(), x))).size()`   which includes iterator-constructor of 'set', which is O(n)

Comment: It's O(log n) to find the item, but to convert the item to a rank within the set is O(n) unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
std::set<MyT> mySet;
```

use:

```
std::set<std::pair<MyT,int>> mySet;
```

Then, for example:

```
//inserting a std::vector<MyT> myVec:
for (int i=0; i<myVec.size(); i++)
      mySet.insert( std::pair<MyT,int>(myVec[i], i) );
```

The sorted result:

```
for (auto it=mySet.begin(); it!=mySet.end(); ++it)
  cout << it->first << " index=" << it->second << "\n";
```